# Why postgres doesn't use multiple indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing

We have a table schema like below

```
user_id UUID
tenant_id UUID
content_id UUID
created_at timestamp
```

There are close to 12 million records as of now. when running a query like below:

```
SELECT * FROM content
    WHERE tenant_id = 'uuid1'
    AND user_id IN ('uuid2')
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

it takes some times close to a minute.

There are indexes on tenant_user_filter_index(tenant_id, user_id) and (created_at desc).
I ran explain analyze, either it used the created_at_idx and filter out results or sometimes it using the tenant_user_filter_index and then doing top N heap sort.

Sample explain analyze:

```
Limit  (cost=561.88..562.13 rows=100 width=24) (actual time=21967.512..21967.529 rows=100 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=258 read=1265
  I/O Timings: read=21946.089
  ->  Sort  (cost=561.88..562.22 rows=136 width=24) (actual time=21967.510..21967.519 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: created_at DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
        Buffers: shared hit=258 read=1265
        I/O Timings: read=21946.089
        ->  Index Scan using tenant_user_filter_index on content  (cost=0.56..557.06 rows=136 width=24) (actual time=69.727..21962.150 rows=27666 loops=1)
"              Index Cond: ((tenant_id = 'uuid1'::uuid) AND (user_id = 'uuid2'::uuid)))"
              Buffers: shared hit=255 read=1265
              I/O Timings: read=21946.089
Planning Time: 0.573 ms
Execution Time: 21967.559 ms
```

I ran analyze command also to update query planner.

Please let me know what could be possible issues to look into

Comment: Does it help to replace `user_id IN ('uuid2')` with `user_id = 'uuid2'`?

Comment: It's the index scan that takes a lot of time, not the sort. The sort takes just 5 milliseconds, there is not much to gain over there. What you could do, is to include created_at in the index tenant_user_filter_index as well. Then the query could stop when it has 100 records, instead of collecting all 27666 rows.

Comment: @fafl no it does not.

Comment: @FrankHeikens yeah, will be trying that. Also noticing when testing the query on replica, it takes much lesser. Probably could be wrt number of connections handled already.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to combine two indexes where one is used for the `WHERE` clause and the other for `ORDER BY`. That's not a shortcoming, it lies in the nature of things: rows returned by the first index are the correct ones, but in the wrong order and vice versa.

If you want both the `WHERE` condition and `ORDER BY` supported by an index, you have to create a single index that can do it all:

```
CREATE INDEX ON content (tenant_id, user_id, created_at);
```